# Why can't SQL Server tell me which column is causing the error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a pretty standard

```
INSERT INTO [table] (col1, col2, ...coln)
select * from #temp
```

and I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int.

I understand the error, but want to know why the column that is causing issue isn't identified by the error message. Is there an easy way to find which column contains the naughty null or is this just a ploy to make me look like I'm being productive at work while I really just spent 30 minutes looking at a huge result set without getting anywhere?

Edit: Thanks for the help guys, but no one really answered the question. Do all RDBMS's spew out similar error messages are or some more helpful? Its 2012...trial and error over possibly thousands of columns should be dead!

Comment: It's annoying - agreed - but there's no way to find this, really, other than trial & error. On any column you expect to be numeric, try using `ISNUMERIC(columnName)` and see if you get any unexpected values of `0`

Comment: When I get an error like that, I know that, being a programmer myself, I did not earn the right for better error messages, because my own error messages are equally cryptic :)

Comment: @randy irrelevant...I simplified it for the example

Comment: @dasblinkenlight cryptic error messages are excusable when you have less than 134999 colleagues and sell your product for less than $7500 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look at how you populate the temp table. You appear to be getting a value of 'null' not NULL. If this data is coming from a Excel file, this is a common problem. I usually clease the data first by updating this way:

```
Update #temp
set field1 = NULL
where field1 = 'NULL'
```

If you want to do all in the same update command, then

```
Update #temp
set field1 = NULLIF(field1, 'NULL')
, field2 = NULLIF(field2, 'NULL')
, field3 = NULLIF(field3, 'NULL')
```

Comment: is there a quick way to do this for all fields?

Comment: @HLGEM: You have a bug where you're updating field3 to field2. Also I'd recommend using: `, field3 = NULLIF(field3, 'NULL')`

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't take you 30 minutes to figure out where the null is. You only have so many columns. Just start selecting from #temp WHERE col1 IS NULL, then WHERE col2 is.

If #temp has a VARCHAR column you're trying to put into in INT column then cast it. If there are NULLs you might want to handle them with an CAST(ISNULL(VarCharColumn, '0') AS INT) or something. If an INT column allows NULLS, then just the cast to INT should be enough (as long as all the values are NULL or a valid int).

If you write your INSERT with a little bit more care then you should be able to get the results you want.

Comment: only so many columns is around 150! Finally solved it now so that's around 1 and a half hours of monkey work, including the errors that followed. All errors were around inserting 'null' s from excel.

Comment: @woggles That... that is a ridiculous amount of columns. I'm glad I'm not working in that schema. My condolences.

Comment: thanks! unfortunately the number of columns per table is not the worst part of the schema!

Comment: It's also a bad idea to use a database that puts you through an exercise of fatigue to figure out what it is too stupid and lazy to simply tell you: like every other database.

Comment: Alright, if we all agree MSSQL sucks that I'm lucky I don't have to work with it much. I'll retract the above comment. Shall I delete it, or it leave it for historical reference?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need some trial and error as @Jeremy pointed out. But you can winnow down the choices.

The error message says that the problem is a NULL in a varchar column. You can restrict your searching to just the varchar columns in #temp: `select * from #temp where col1 is null or col3 is null`

Second, the problem is also happening when the database engine tries to convert a null varchar value to an `integer not null`. Compare the definitions of both tables to see where a varchar in #temp matches up with an `integer not null` in the other table.

This, however, is suspicious. Why are you trying to convert text to numbers? If that's what you really want to do, you will probably need an explicit cast from textual to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

If you run these two statements before your query you will see null values on those columns in the results set:

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
```