# Why doesn't SQL Server tell me which field is causing the error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When doing a sql insert, it may fail because one of the fields will fail to validate. There is a variety of validations that may fail. For example I have recently seen:

```
[22003] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric. (8115)
```

and

```
[22001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated. (8152)
```

It is quite frustrating to go hunting for the troublesome field when you have many columns and are inserting many rows at a time with prepared statements. Why can't Sql Server tell me which field is problematic? Please note I am not looking on how to solve these individual errors, but rather a more fundamental question why better error messages are not implemented.

Edit: [Why can't SQL Server tell me which column is causing the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878645/why-cant-sql-server-tell-me-which-column-is-causing-the-error) that this is being marked a duplicate off doesn't actually answer the question. The accepted answer there doesn't address the question so putting a bounty on it will do nothing.

Comment: Yes. No one answered that question though an answer as accepted (by mistake imo).  Author wrote "Edit: Thanks for the help guys, but no one really answered the question. Do all RDBMS's spew out similar error messages are or some more helpful? Its 2012...trial and error over possibly thousands of columns should be dead!"

Comment: The questions may be similar, but "Why can't SQL Server tell me which column is causing the error" hasn't actually been answered. Why the down vote then?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the usual protocol would be to put a bounty on the question in the link, instead of opening a new question, to draw attention to it.

Comment: @Roger: what would you expect as an answer for that?

Comment: @Quassnoi, I would expect something along the lines of what Ian P said, but more definite. I want to know what is going on inside the guts of the RDBMS that makes this difficult. An alternative though less satisfying answer would be "This has been fixed in SQL Server Version++".

Comment: @Roger: there is nothing that would theoretically prevent `SQL Server` from doing that. As for why haven't they done it... a camel's been asked: "why is your neck curved"? He thought for a moment and then replied: "sorry, and what's straight in me?"

Comment: "*Why doesn't Product X do Y?*" questions are generally matters of opinion and subjective discussion, and not well-suited to a strict Q+A forum like this one.  *Sometimes* such a question can be fairly answered as "there's no practical way that Y could be done in X", but usually the only possible answer is "*because that's how they decided to do it*".

Answer (score 1):

Well SQL is a set based engine and the logic of sets is boolean. Either data is in a set or it isnt. Yes / No. There are a lot of fancy techniques employed to simply get your set back to your client ASAP. My guess is that if you started checking individual values inside the set, you'd shoot performance in the head so badly that it would hand customers to competing rdbms hand over fist. Yes its annoying when an insert fails, but dividing data in half to find where the exception is will get you down quite quickly. You can then improve your design approach to prevent the problem reoccuring. (less sloppy, more robust)

But you'd have to ask somone on the SQL dev team for a definitive answer, my guess is they would give you three reasons: performance, performance and of course scalable peformance.   HTH